# What parameter should be passed for pointers char* in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, parameters, dllimport

i have a third-party dll written c++ that i have imported in c# using `DllImport`.

they also provided a documentation for calling functions. some function were easy to handle that don't have any parameter passed. now i don't know how to call a function with pointer parameters passed in c# like in a following image.

[image]

here's my code

```
 [DllImport(third-parth.dll")]
    public static extern int ReadInfo( ref StringBuilder MagInfo, ref StringBuilder TicketNumber,  string BmpFileNamePath, int PicFormat);


    public int read_info()
    {
       StringBuilder Mag = new StringBuilder(100);
        string path = "folder";
        return ReadInfo( ref Mag, ref Mag, path,1);


    }
```

Saw this example on https://stackoverflow.com/a/28497747

EDIT:

```
    StringBuilder Mag = new StringBuilder(100);
        StringBuilder ticket = new StringBuilder(100);
        string path = @"D:\folder";
        return ReadInfo( Mag, ticket, path,0);
```

also i have tried both calling conventions

and i found this in one of c++ file may help to figure out.

```
typedef int (__stdcall *ReadInfo)(char* MagInfo, char* TicketNumber, char* BmpFileNamePath, int PicFormat);
```

EDIT:2

Here's how function is being called in c++ demo

```
 int CScanChequeDllDemo_VCDlg::ReadImage_BackSide()
{
    //*************************************************************
    //Read back side image data status, user can read back side image.  
    if(Global_DevStatus.iStatus == SCANCHEQUE_STATUS_SCAN_REVERSED)
    {
        //*************************************************************
        //have image data
        if(Global_DevStatus.iHaveData != 0)
        {
            memset(Global_MagInfo, 0x00, sizeof(Global_MagInfo));
            memset(Global_TicketNumber, 0x00, sizeof(Global_TicketNumber));
            memset(Global_BmpFileNamePath, 0x00, sizeof(Global_BmpFileNamePath));

            //*************************************************************
            //Read back side image data
            Global_returnValue = U_ReadInfo(Global_MagInfo, Global_TicketNumber,Global_BmpFileNamePath, Global_PicFormat);

            //refresh picture
            ShowImage(this,NULL);

            //show status
            ShowStatus(Global_returnValue); 
        
            if(Global_returnValue == SCANCHEQUE_ERROR_WRITEFILE)
            {
                //wait for instruction from the application software
            }
            
            //*************************************************************
            //Get device status 
            Global_returnValue = U_QueryStatus(&Global_DevStatus);
            if(Global_returnValue != SCANCHEQUE_SUCCESS)
            {
                ShowStatus(Global_returnValue);
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here's global variable

```
char                            Global_MagInfo[1024]            = {0x00};                   
char                            Global_TicketNumber[1024]       = {0x00};                   
char                            Global_BmpFileNamePath[1024]    = {0x00};                   
int                             Global_PicFormat                = (IMAGE_FORMAT_BMP | IMAGE_FORMAT_JPG | IMAGE_FORMAT_TIFF);//reversed
```

Comment: Try specifying the CharSet as `CharSet.Ansi`, (a char in C is always 8 bits wide) -look at the example, how they decorated the DllImport attribute. The other is that you don't require passing the string builders by reference.  Try without the ref modifiers.

Comment: @BlueStrat got this error after modifying code "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: I noticed that you are passing the same StringBuilder instance to both MagInfo and TicketNumber parameters. Can you try creating two separate instances, one for each parameter?

Comment: @BlueStrat already tried

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes that I can see. You presumably need to allocate two instances of `StringBuilder`, as pointed out in the comments. And the `StringBuilder` arguments should not have `ref`.

It is possible that the calling convention is wrong. We can't be sure what it should be from the code shown in the question.

I would also recommend being explicit about the character set, although the default is ANSI so that won't be an issue of correctness.

Comment: I already tried these but still noting. i have edit question i think that can help to figure it out

Comment: Once you remove the two ref keywords, the C# matches the C++ typedef. I don't know what "still nothing" means.

Comment: i am getting `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: It's plausible that's caused by something we can't see

Comment: I dont know what i am missing here. i have everything demo + documentation. but i am noob when it comes to pointers and c++. anyways i have updated question with a demo function calling `ReadInfo()`

Comment: That code appears to regard the third argument as a buffer to be populated by the callee. Which is not how the doc looks. Use a StringBuilder for that arg too.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question maybe it will help someone

```
  [DllImport(@yourDLL", EntryPoint ="ReadInfo", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern int ReadInfo(IntPtr MagInfo, IntPtr TicketNumber,  IntPtr BmpFileNamePath,int picFormat);

    public int read_info()
    {

        
        IntPtr m = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
        IntPtr t = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
        IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);


        int result = ReadInfo(m, t, p, 0);

        string mginfo = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(m);
        string tinfo = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(t);
        string pth = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(p);

        Console.WriteLine(mginfo);
        Console.WriteLine(pth);
       
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(m);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(t);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
        return result;
     

    }
```